# Is there an easy way to style a WPF Grid like Mahapps Metro DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, grid, mahapps.metro

We are using Mahapps.Metro in our project and for one part of the project we need to use a Grid. The default grid is fairly plain and I wondered if anyone knows of an (easy) way to style the default Grid like the Mahapps.Metro DataGrid for consistency.

I.e. i want this:

[image]

To look like this:

[image]

Comment: You mean the WPF DataGrid? Otherwise the question won't make sense.

Comment: Sorry if its unclear! I meant I would like the same styling on the standard WPF Grid that Mahapps metro applies to the standard WPF DataGrid. I.e. header colors, borders, etc

Comment: Grid is a layout Panel. It doesn't have any headers or borders.

Comment: I understand that - but i wanted to apply the same (or similar) style to the grid. i.e. i am putting data into it (non editable) and i want it to appear the same or similar. I understand that it wont be a simple copy and paste.

Comment: i don't want the functionality of the datagrid. I want to put a grid of information onto the screen, and i want the grid to be styled like the WPF DataGrid (Styled by mahapps metro)  for consistency. That's all. Nothing special, just styling.

Comment: Styling of what? A Grid does not have any stylable "data" of its own. It just arranges other UI elements, which could of course be styled individually, but not by a Grid Style.

Comment: @MercifulGiraffe Sure, you can style anything to look like anything in WPF. Is it fixed with 2 columns? That'll make it even easier. Do you want the columns width hardcoded or sized to something?

Comment: @SledgeHammer Yes, 2 columns. 50% width of space each. Ideally, with the row highlighting (not essential!)

Comment: @MercifulGiraffe, if you want row highlighting, use the DataGrid or a ListBox or a ListView and re-style it, re-inventing it and everything that goes into it is a LOT of work. Otherwise, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, without row highlighting, it's pretty easy. Here is some XAML pseudo-code:

```
Grid
   RowDefinition Auto    Header
   RowDefinition 1       Rectangle
   RowDefinition *       Items

Row0 = Grid with:

   ColumnDefinition 50*   Text
   ColumnDefinition 1     Rectangle
   ColumnDefinition 50*   Text

Row1 = Rectangle

Row2 = ItemsControl ItemTemplate would be a Grid with:

   ColumnDefinition 50*   Text
   ColumnDefinition 1     Rectangle
   ColumnDefinition 50*   Text
```

You wouldn't have resizing or row highlighting or selection or anything like that. If you want scrolling, you can put the ItemsControl inside a ScrollViewer.

Comment: Based on your comments above I suspect that i should be using a listview (or even the datagrid), but this actually answers my question as posed. Thank you.